# Retrofit - Parse XML with list of elements using SimpleXmlConverterFactory

Tags: android, xml, arraylist, retrofit2, simple-xml-converter

The XML content that returns from server:

`<root>
    <option value="ROW VALUE1">ROW CONTENT1</option>
    <option value="ROW VALUE2">ROW CONTENT2</option>
</root>`

My representation for `option` object:

```
public class Option {
    @Element(name = "option")
    private String option;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String value;
}
```

My representation for `Response` object:

```
@Root(name = "root")
public class GetOptionsResponse
{
    @ElementList(entry = "option", inline = true)
    private ArrayList<Option> mOptionList;
}
```

But anytime I tried to run the code and parse it, I got:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=option, required=true, type=void) on field 'option' private java.lang.String com.packagename.models.Option.option for class com.packagename.models.Option at line 1`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try with `@Text` instead of `@Element(name = "option")`

Comment: @Blackbelt Hi it works!!! you are my hero :)
So what the hack is the problem with `Element`?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I had  this issue in the past (~4 months ago) and I fixed this way